# Leading term asymptotic integral containing logarithm

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

I want to get the leading term in the asymptotic of the integral $$\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha}}\ln\frac{x+a}{x-a} \,dx$$ for $a\to +\infty$. Here $a>0$ and $\alpha>\frac{3}{2}$ to ensure integrability at infinity.
My main concern is the integrable singularity in $a$. Usually I do an appropriate change of variables to remove it, but I can't seem to find an appropriate one.

Comment: Could you please correct you question - make the formula visible?

Comment: You could make the change $x\to{t}$: $x=at$. After that you will deal only with the integrand at $a\to{\infty}$

Comment: Don't I still get singularity in t=1?

Comment: You get it anyway at $x=a$. Logarithmic singularity is integrable

Comment: I know it is integrable. I have always treated those integrable singularity by changing variables to remove them. I don't know how to treat them for the asymptotic calculation if present. So please, if you know how to do it, explain it to me.

Comment: I'm not fast at taking integrals - I will do, but, probably, somebody will do it quicker. It is evident that after this change the integral looks $a^4\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{t^3}{(1+a^2t^2)^{\alpha}}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1} dt$. If you look for the leading asymptotics term you may drop 1 in the denominator: $I(a,\alpha)\sim{a}^{4-2\alpha}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{t^3}{(t^2)^{\alpha}}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1} dt$

Comment: Ok, I can drop the one since I am far from zero. I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we make a change $x=ta$. The integral becomes $I(a, \alpha)=a^4\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^3}{(1+a^2t^2)^{\alpha}}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1} \,dt=a^{4-2\alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{3-2\alpha}}{(1+\frac{1}{a^2t^2})^{\alpha}}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1} \,dt$.

Integral converges; the only (integrable) singularity is at $t=1$.

We can expand the integrand into the series
$$I(a,\alpha)=a^{4-2\alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{3-2\alpha}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1}{(1-\frac{\alpha}{a^21!}\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)}{a^42!}\frac{1}{t^4}+...)} \,dt$$ where all integrals converge ($3-2\alpha<1$ and $\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1}\sim\frac{1}{t}$ at $t\to\infty$)

The mian asymptotics term is $a^{4-2\alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{3-2\alpha}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1}dt=a^{4-2\alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{b}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1}dt$

where $b=3-2\alpha$.

It seems that the easiest way to evaluate the integral $J(b)=\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{b}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1}dt=\int_{0}^{1}x^{-b-2}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}dx$  ($t=\frac{1}{x}$) is to expand the integrand into the series:

$J(b)=2\int_{0}^{1}x^{-b-2}\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+...\right)dx=2\left(\frac{1}{-b}+\frac{1}{3(-b+2)}+\frac{1}{5(-b+4)}+...\right)=$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{k-\frac{b}{2}}=\frac{1}{-b-1}\left(\Psi(-\frac{b}{2})-\Psi(\frac{1}{2})\right)$,

where $\Psi$ is digamma function: $\Psi(1+s)=-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+s}-\frac{1}{k}\right)$

Finally, we get the main asymptotics term$$I(a, \alpha)\sim{a}^{4-2\alpha}\frac{1}{2(\alpha-2)}\left(\Psi(\alpha-\frac{3}{2})-\Psi(\frac{1}{2})\right)$$

At $\alpha\to2$ we have to disclose the uncertainty

$I(a,\alpha\to2)\sim\frac{{a}}{2}^{0}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left(\Psi(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)-\Psi(\frac{1}{2})\right)=\frac{1}{2}\Psi'(\frac{1}{2})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2k-1)^2}$

$$I(a,\alpha=2)\sim\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{-1}\ln\frac{t+1}{t-1}dt=\frac{3}{2}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Other asymptotics terms can be evaluated in the same way.

Comment: $\sum_{k \geq 0} 1/(2 (k + 1/2) (k - b/2))$ should be $(\psi(1/2) - \psi(-b/2))/(b + 1)$.

Comment: I think when you expand $J(b)$ into the power series something has gone wrong, after this step your $J(b)$ no longer agrees with a numerical result. Possible reasons: the series is outside the radius of convergence of $\ln(1\pm x)$, ($|x|<1$). Also there will be terms in there that have powers $>-b-2$, which integrate to $\infty$. And maybe there is an issue with the logarithm branch cut?

Comment: There is a typo - integration of J(b) is from 0 to 1, not to $\infty$. Just corrected

Comment: @Maxim You are right - wrote an extra two. Thank you. Just correcting

Comment: @Svyatoslav No it's good now. I was looking at an old version of your post. My bad!

Comment: @Sal Good luck :)